# htaccess url regex display "&" if backreference is matched

Tags: regex, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I'm using IsapiRewriter on IIS6, but I think this question is more general than that. I'm also pretty sure there's no way to do it, but decided I should ask folks who know more regex than I do before giving up completely.

I'm matching url tails like the following:

```
^/term1(\?)?(.*)
```

which successfully matches

```
http://domain.tld/term1?utm=1234
```

and when used in a pattern like

```
^/term1(\?)?(.*)   /term1handler.aspx$1$2 [I]
```

quite properly redirects

```
http://domain.tld/term1?utm=1234
```

to

```
http://domain.tld/term1handler.aspx?utm=1234
```

However, some of my redirections need to redirect to something with a query string parameter already in the output. The existing redirect looks like

```
^/term1   /term1handler.aspx?ID=12345 [I]
```

I'd like to find a solution that allows me to replace $1 with an ampersand if there's a match there so that I end up with

```
http://domain.tld/term1handler.aspx?ID=12345&utm=1234
```

Is there a regex pattern that can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your rule should be using %{QUERY_STRING} and must use QSA flag in RewriteFlag like this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(utm=.*)$
RewriteRule ^term1/?$ term1handler.aspx?%1 [R,L,QSA,NE]
```

QSA flag will make sure to append `utm=1234` query parameter with additional query parameter `ID=12345` thus making a composite REQUEST_URI like `/term1handler.aspx?ID=12345&utm=1234`

From the manual http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html

**'qsappend|QSA' (query string append)**
This flag forces the rewrite engine to append a query string part of the substitution string to the existing string, instead of replacing it. Use this when you want to add more data to the query string via a rewrite rule.

Also using `NE` (no escape) here to take care of presence of special characters `(;, %, $ etc)` in query parameters.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to the QSA flag - I'd never heard of that one.  FWIW, the final solution just required using the QSA flag in each rule - I agree that in general using the %{QUERY_STRING} condition would be better, but with the mechanism I'm using to generate the rules from a database using the condition would be a little cumbersome.